# Doing calculations in a SQL Server view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am new to T-SQL and SQL in general and need help with a calculation I need to do within an view.

In the underlying database table I have six columns "Date", "Account", "Opening Balance", "Debit", "Credit" and "Balance_cumulative". I now need to calculate a new column "Balance_cumulative_new", where from the beginning of the "Opening Balance" of period 1, the debit and credit values are continuously carried on.

I suggest you see the attached screenshot to better understand what I mean: [TSQL Calculation of "Balance_cumulative_new"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQfE2.jpg)

Please consider, that other than in the example shown, the database consists of multiple accounts and periods.

I apologize for my rather bad English and appreciate your help.

Best regards,
Kalusha9

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your goal. Images of data are often no helpful, as the volunteers here can't interact with them. When supplying data supply it as what is it, `text`; or even better as DDL (`CREATE`) and DML (`INSERT`) statements. With your sample data show your expected results. If you have multiple of something (accounts) include multiple in your sample and expected data. Finally, show us what you've tried as well. If you haven't tried anything, why not? That's the first thing you should be doing. Have a go yourself first and then share your attempt. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a running total, which in SQL Server you can calculate with [SUM window function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). You will partition your running total by account and calculate it over date. So your view will look like this:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView
as
select
    [Date]
    , [Account]
    , [Opening Balance]
    , [Debit]
    , [Credit]
    , [Balance_cumulative]
    , SUM([Balance_cumulative]) OVER(PARTITION BY [Account] ORDER BY [DATE]) as [Balance_cumulative_new]
from MyTable
```

Comment: Thanks Andrey, that got me a step closer to the solution. How can I calculate a sum, with the following condition: SUM(([Opening Balance] WHERE [Date] = '01.01.2017') + [Debit] + [Credit]). I hope you understand what I mean. The running total should only consist of the Opening Balance dated 01.01.2017 and not include the Opening Balance dated 01.01.2018.

Comment: No, I do not understand. Do you mean that the running total should be per year too? i.e. `SUM([Balance_cumulative]) OVER(PARTITION BY [Account], YEAR([Date]) ORDER BY [DATE])`

Comment: Andrey, with your help/input I finally got it working ! :) The code that did it for me is as follows: sum((case when Date = '20170101' then [Opening Balance] else 0 end) + [Debit] + [Credit]) OVER(PARTITION BY [Account] ORDER BY [Date]) as Balance_cumulative_new

Comment: Cool! It will be greatly appreciated if you accept my answer in this case